# If you fail a timed quest, are you penalized?

Tags: stardew-valley

The board in front of Pierre's often offers 2-day timed quests. I haven't noticed if failing these quests penalizes me somehow (for instance, lowering my reputation with the quest-giver).

Does failing a quest have any consequences?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thankfully, failing a timed quest does not have any bad consequences. Even if you fail one of those, your relationships and your reputation will stay intact.

Comment: The way I think of it is, they put up a sign on the board saying "hey can someone bring me a `thing` by `date`?" and the PC simply takes note of it. If you don't bring a `thing` to them by `date`, they're not going to dislike you specifically for it - they don't know you wrote that quest down in your journal, after all.